# how to repeat (2, 1) tensors to (50, 1) tensors in TensorFlow 1.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

For example,

```
# x is a tensor
print(x)
[1, 0] 

# after repeating it
print(x)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

There is no `tf.repeat` in `TensorFlow 1.10` so if there is the best replaceable way to implement it?

Comment: You should probably also report how you do produce `x` and what are your boundary conditions... this task is very easy in NumPy, for example... and without additional information it would be straightforward to suggest to use it and then move back and forth whatever object type you are after.

Comment: @norok2 But there is no `tensor.numpy()` in `tf 1.10`, and `tensor.eval()` can't be used when session is registered so maybe it is hard to use `numpy` to solve this problme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can really only use Tensorflow `1.10` then try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 0])
x = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(x, -1), [1, 25]), (50, 1))
print(x)

'''
tf.Tensor(
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0], shape=(50, 1), dtype=int32)
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go with this

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1, 0])
temp = tf.zeros(shape=(25, 2), dtype=tf.int32)

result = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(temp + x), (-1,))
```